# Where to start... controlling access to code files using Visual Studio in multi-developer environment

Tags: visual-studio, workflow, dreamweaver

We are in the midst of transitioning from asp, vbscript, SQL Server 2000, to asp.net mvc, sql server 2008.

When we were using classic asp, we could use Dreamweaver to lock access to a file on the network so that developers and designers wouldn't overwrite each other's changes when saving.

Is there an equivalent feature in Visual Studio 2010? Or, are there other techniques to accomplish this?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I guess I need to get the server guys involved to make this happen. I'm going to forward this to them for review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There [most definitely are](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control) techniques to accomplish this.

Based on the upgrade, it sounds like the team is moving forward.  Maybe that means business is good, maybe that means the team is growing or will grow, etc.  In any event, and even if it's just a single developer, file locking to prevent overwriting each other's changes is no solution at all.  Proper source control should *always* be used.

Visual Studio has support for TFS, naturally, but there are plugins for other (free) systems.  [SVN is a good one](http://www.visualsvn.com/) to get started.  (Though, personally, I don't like IDE integration of source control.  I prefer to see it as a file operation and not a code operation, and therefore prefer the [Tortoise](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) revision control clients for their Windows Explorer integration.)

Answer (score 0):

You will almost certainly want to transition to a proper version control system.

Subversion is very popular and works well for most.  TortoiseSVN is an extremely useful Explorer extension to make Subversion easy to use.  There are also plugins for development environments.  VisualSVN (not free) and AnkhSVN both integrate Subversion into Visual Studio.

Git & Mercurial are also very popular.  Both are designed with distributed teams more in mind.  They work largely the same as Subversion, but each version control system has slightly different "best practices" when it comes to work flow, particularly around branching and merging.

Answer (score 0):

@quakkels: Go for TFS. I deeply hate it, but it will be easier for you.
SVN is for geeks, and GIT is for alpha-geeks (or for wanabes like me).